# What does “request for member '*******' in something not a structure or union” mean?

Tags: c++, c, struct

Is there an easy explanation for what this error means?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct student {
        char Surname[30];
        char Name[30];
        int Age;
        char Address[10];

};

int main(){
     int i;
     char temp1;
     char temp2;
     int temp3;;
     char temp4;
     struct student x[2];
     for(i=1; i<3; i++){
              struct student x[i];
             printf(" Surname of Student %s:", i);
             scanf("%s",&temp1);
             printf(" Other names of Student %s:", i);
             scanf("%s",&temp2);
             printf(" Age of Student %s:", i);
             scanf("%s",&temp2);
             printf(" Address of Student %s:", i);
             scanf("%s",&temp3);
             strcpy(x->Surname,&temp1);
             strcpy(x->Name,&temp2);
             //x[i].Surname=temp1;
             //x[i].Name=temp2;
             x[i].Age=temp3;
             //x[i].Address=temp4;
             strcpy(x->Address,&temp4);

             }
     int temp;
     if (x[1].Age > x[2].Age){
                     temp = 1;
                     printf(x.Surname[temp]);
                     printf(x.Name[temp]);
                     printf(x.Age[temp]);
                     printf(x.Address[temp]);
                  }
     else if(x[1].Age < x[2].Age){
                     temp = 2;
                     printf(x.Surname[temp]);
                     printf(x.Name[temp]);
                     printf(x.Age[temp]);
                     printf(x.Address[temp]);
                  }
     else{
                     printf(x.Surname[1]);
                     printf(x.Name[1]);
                     printf(x.Age[1]);
                     printf(x.Address[1]);

                     printf(x.Surname[2]);
                     printf(x.Name[2]);
                     printf(x.Age[2]);
                     printf(x.Address[2]);

                      }

     return 0;









};
```

im getting the error request for member `Surname' in something not a structure or union... Its actually for all the print lines... Can someone please help me with this? im new to C programming....

Comment: `x` is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: x is an array, not a top-level *structure* variable (thus this: `x.Surname[temp]` is going to choke your compiler). I bet that "request for member ... in something not a structure" makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: There are more issues in this code than what you're asking for help with.  For example, `printf(" Surname of Student %s:", i);` is expecting to print a character string, not an int.  `for(i=1; i<3; i++){` accesses your array outside the bounds.  Array indexes start at 0.

Comment: You have two declarations for `x`, one as an array of 2 `struct student` objects, and another as a variable-length array of `i` `struct student` objects.

Comment: @chris A raw array gets implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element.

Comment: @bames53, But not used like this in `x->Surname`.

Comment: @bames53 It works even there. Equivalent to `(*x).Surname`.

Comment: @chris As luser droog says, it works even fine there.

Comment: @bames53, Huh, I can't seem to replicate it without getting a compiler error in both C and C++, but that sounds extremely terrible.

Comment: @bames53, Never mind, I was stupidly using an int array instead of the small structure I created for some reason. This is vile.

Comment: For the sake of security: For non hardccoded strings never use `printf(string);` but always use `printf("%s", string);`

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
                 printf(x.Surname[temp]);
```

to

```
                 printf(x[temp].Surname);
```

Whether `x` is a pointer or an array, you can't take a struct member out of it.

There's other weirdness in your code. Particularly here:

```
 struct student x[2]; // this array never receives data because the other x shadows it
 for(i=1; i<3; i++){
          struct student x[i]; // this declaration shadows the earlier declaration
```

My guess is that you intended to do something more like

```
 struct student x[2];
 for(i=0; i<2; i++){
          struct student *ptr = &x[i];
```

Then your usage of the arrow operator `->` would make more sense, too.

Also, this is a problem:

```
                 printf(x.Age[temp]);
```

even after we fix the struct access to

```
                 printf(x[temp].Age);
```

You can't pass an integer to printf like that. A string can serve as a format string, but for an integer you must give a format specification in a string.

```
                 printf("%d", x[temp].Age);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this code has more bugs than a cheap motel.

A glaring bug is this:

```
scanf("%s",&temp1);
```

The "%s" format string expects a pointer to a character array where it can put the string, including the null character. But you have declared temp1 like this: `char temp1`, which is a single character. Unless your names have the length of 0, you will have a problem. Better define it like this:

```
char temp1[30];
```

or directly write to the member of your struct and skip the `strcpy`:

```
scanf("%s", x[i].Surname);
```

then you have space for up to at least 29 characters. But you still have a problem if the user desides to enter more than 29 characters.